# Processing newline character in function jquery.i18n.prop()

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, localization, internationalization

JQuery code is as follows:

```
alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('message.key'));
```

The value is specified in the properties file as:

```
message.key=value is after newline\nValue here
```

Following output is expected  from javascript alert():

```
value is after newline
Value here
```

The actual output is:

```
value is after newline\nValue here
```

I tried different methods by changing value stored in properties file to:

- message.key=value is after newline\\nValue here
- message.key=value is after newline\u000DValue here

But it doesn't work. It displays "\\n" instead

What changes are required to be made to get the desired output?

EDIT: Following code gives desired output in javascript:

```
alert('value is after newline\nValue here')
```

But I need to use jquery.i18n.properties for localization

Comment: The solution is to use Unicode character \u000d and not \u000D. It was so simple, but took some time to find :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just go like this (the plugin supports multi-line properties):

```
message.key1=value is after newline
Value here
message.key2=next value
```

Comment: Hey Shane, thanks for the reply. But it inserts spaces and not newline. By the way, multi-line statements have to end with "\"

Comment: I found the solution. I've posted it in the comment for question.